# Apache2 as proxy to a docker container and HTTPs and PHP. Rewriting HTTP to HTTPS is not working

Tags: php, docker, apache

I'm in the process of migrating multiple web pages written in PHP from the host into a docker container, on the same host.

A request comes in via HTTP**s**, apache decrypts and forwards the request directly to container ip:port via HTTP.

In the container the requests are processed by an other Apache instance and php8.1-fpm.

The page is up and running, Apache2 on Ubuntu is presenting the right certificate for the particular domain, however, forms are sent to the client with HTTP URI instead of HTTPs.

Normally this, could/should be fixed by writing a `RewriteRule` which I've tried in multiple ways without any success.

Here's the latest version of the apache config for that host.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName demo.myapp.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.demo.myapp.mydomain.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://ip.ip.ip.ip:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://ip.ip.ip.ip:80/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /data/var/www/mydomain.com/data/certbot/conf/live/demo.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /data/var/www/mydomain.com/data/certbot/conf/live/demo.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

In the browser console I get this error:
[image]

Any thought no how to fix the problem?

Comment: Apache knows that _inbound requests_ are crossing the HTTP/HTTPS boundary, but your app doesn't necessarily and is probably generating responses that have `http://` URLs in them, such as the form target. You need to fix you app to generate appropriate URLs. One option is to set a custom header in the proxy config that denotes the protocol that the request came in via, and reference that header in your app to switch between `http://` and `https://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use always an additional setting:

```
ProxyPass ...
ProxyPassReverse ...
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
```

It is a defacto standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto
Most dockers images evaluate this setting.